# Linear evolution PDE: exponential decay to equilibrium

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Suppose I have a homogeneous linear evolution equation

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
u_t + Lu = 0,&x\in\Omega,\quad t> 0  \\
u(0,x) = f(x) & x\in\Omega \\
u(t,x) = 0, & x\in\partial\Omega
\end{array}\right.
$$ Is there a general condition that we can place on $L$ to guarantee that solutions of the above decay *exponentially* to equilibrium?  I sense this is related to Hille-Yosida but I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sufficient condition is that the bilinear form induced by $L$ is bounded and coercive in $H^1_0(\Omega)$. Then testing the equation with $u(t)$ and integrating from $0$ to $T$ should yield exponential decay:
$$
\|u(T)\|_{L^2}^2 + \alpha \int_0^T \|u(t)\|_{L^2}^2 dt\le \|f\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2,
$$
you have to use Gronwall inequality here.

Then you get exponential decay for your equation with $L=-\Delta$ due to the homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions.

I guess this statement is far from optimal, however, the exponential decay can be proved and checked relatively easily.